# jooq - Add code to the generated Record class

Tags: java, jooq

I learning how to work with jooq. I would like to know if I can add some domain-level methods in to the generated Record classes.

Suppose the record was this:

```
public class ConCalCompanyRecord extends org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl<com.aesthete.csmart.connect.model.db.gen.tables.records.ConCalCompanyRecord> implements org.jooq.Record6<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp> {

// properties
// getters and setters

// I would like to add a method like this:
   public void isABlueCompany(){
     // work with the fields
   }

}
```

But I know if I do this, as soon as I generate this class again from the DB, all my changes will get lost. So what is the recommended way of doing this?

A wrapper class? A sub class to the record? If its any of these, how do I get jooq to recognise these classes at the time of fetching. For example:

```
connectionFacade.getDSLContext()
            .selectFrom(CON_CAL_INSTANCE)
            .where(CON_CAL_INSTANCE.DATE.between(
                    new Date(datesOfTheWeekForDate[0].toDate().getTime()), new Date(datesOfTheWeekForDate[1].toDate().getTime())))
            .orderBy(CON_CAL_INSTANCE.DATE)
            .fetch()
            .into(new RecordHandler<ConCalInstanceRecord>() {
                @Override
                public void next(ConCalInstanceRecord record) {
                    calendarEntries.addToList(new com.aesthete.csmart.connect.model.domain.records.ConCalInstance(record));
                   }
            });
```

In the above case I am providing a wrapper called ConCalInstance to the record class. Do I have to write a RecordHandler like this for every query I execute if I need to use a wrapper? 
What is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Lukas's suggestion I landed up adding code to my generated Record like this

```
public class ConCalInstanceRecord extends org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl....{

     //fields and getter and setters of the generated record..

    private ConCalInstanceBehaviour behaviour;

    public ConCalInstanceBehaviour getBehaviour(){
        if(behaviour==null){
            behaviour=new ConCalInstanceBehaviour(this);
        }
        return behaviour;
    }
}
```

Sort of like the wrapper like I was talking about, but the other way around, the record wraps a behaviour class. I can now add custom behaviour into my behaviour classes without having to go back to the generator every time I needed to add a new method.

This allowed me to access additional domain behaviour like this...

```
record.getBehaviour().doSomething();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override jOOQ's default code generator with your own extensions. This is documented here, in the manual:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/

The example shows how it works:

```
public class MyGenerator extends JavaGenerator {

    @Override
    protected void generateRecordClassFooter(
        TableDefinition table, 
        JavaWriter out
    ) {
        super.generateRecordClassFooter(table, out);

        if ("SOME_TABLE".equals(table.getName())) {
            out.println();
            out.tab(1).println("public void isABlueCompany() {");
            out.tab(2).println("// Your logic here");
            out.tab(1).println("}");
        }
        else if ("SOME_OTHER_TABLE".equals(table.getName())) {
            // [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Lukas.. Thanks for responding. Sorry I should have been clearer. This is not something I would add to the template. These are domain methods. Let me give you an example, an CreditCardRecord could have a method like public boolean isAValidCard(). In this method we will check if the card is valid or not. A UserRecord could have a different method. These are not something you add into the template but rather code it into the object when the need arises

Comment: I could use fetchInto POJO method, and not use the generated Record.. thats one way, I think. How do handle cases such as this, where you want to add more functionality to a returned Record

Comment: My solution will still work for you. Let me add a nother line to clarify... Fact is, you cannot manually add code to your generated records for the reasons you've mentioned.

Comment: I landed up adding code like the one mentioned in my updated question.. Please have a look.. whoever is interested

Comment: @sethu: You could actually add your own answer containing that update, instead of modifying the question. For future visitors of this question, it will be more obviuous to understand how your solution came to be...